# How to correctly quote the `$@` contents in a git alias?

Tags: git, shell

I'm writing a few git aliases, but I can't correctly quote `$@`.

Suppose this alias:

```
test = "!bash -c 'cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; ls -l "${@}"' sh"
```

If I run the folliwing, the first file is not found:

```sh
$ touch "a b" c
$ git test "a b" c
ls: cannot access 'a': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'b': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 0 Sep  4 12:09 c
```

The bash command, when self-standing, works as expected:

```sh
$ bash -c 'cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; ls -l "${@}"' sh "a b" c
```

What's wrong with the alias?

(note that I'm using bash because the real alias is more complex, as it uses array indexing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works for me:

```
test = "!bash -c 'cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; ls -l \"${@}\"' sh"
```

Example:

```
$ git test "a b" c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  4 12:33 a b
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  4 12:33 c
```

In `man git-config` it says:

> Inside double quotes, double quote " and backslash \ characters must
>   be escaped: use \" for " and \\ for \.

Answer (score 2):

As the double quotes around the `${@}` are not escaped, they end the quoting of the whole string you assign to `test`.

Try:

```
test = "!bash -c 'cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; ls -l \"${@}\"' sh"
```